# Encoding special characters into Byte array

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

Few days ago I've asked a question about german special characters.
I can encode and decode characters like ö, ä or ü now. But.. some characters left and I need to encode/decode them too.

For example, characters that fails: ² ³ € µ Ü Ö Ä ~ ´ §

Here is code:

```
    private static byte[] MyGetBytesArray(string data)
    {
        Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
        return enc.GetBytes(data);
    }

    private static string MyGetString(byte[] data)
    {
        Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
        return enc.GetString(data);
    }
```

I'm looking for a solution to encode/decode all characters. I'm writing an encrypt/decrypt algorythm, and I don't know what user will paste into program. I need to give back exactly the same.

Thanks for help, again..

EDIT:
Ok, UnicodeEncoding works (I think). It is my encrypt/decrypt algoryth now:/ I'm still not sure what is going on (I thnik it is sth with zeros. During encoding by Unicode zero is after every character), but encoding special characters wokrs. At least that test was successfull:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(opd.FileName, Encoding.Default);
byte[] byt = getBytesArray(text);
string text2 = getString(byt);

if (text2 == text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("FAIL");
}
```

BTW. Encoding.Default is correct right ?

Comment: That code should be able to convert any character to/from a UTF-8 encoded byte array. What exactly is the problem you are facing? In what ways do the characters you listed fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately those characters are Unicode so you won't be able to use the UTF8Encoding class.

Try using the UnicodeEncoding class instead.

Comment: Unicode is a _character set_, which can be converted to bytes via several standard _encodings_, such as UTF-8 and UTF-16. `UnicodeEncoding` is quite poorly named, as it actually represents the UTF-16 encoding. UTF-8 is capable of representing any Unicode character.

Comment: Well, I doesnt work at all :/ small ü, which was good in UTF8Encoding with UnicodeEncoding fails too.

Comment: @Marshall: See my comment to your question - you need to tell us what you mean by "fails". How are you using the code you showed; what outcome did you expect, and what happened instead?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see it.. i need 15min. I need to check sth

Answer (score 3):

Try UnicodeEncoding instead.

```
var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
return Write(encoding.GetBytes(s));
```